# How to update values on UI with out refreshing page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently creating a web application using spring boot, spring mvc and java to monitor server memory. I am able to get the memory to display on my web page using thymeleaf.

In my java application I am using cth.etz to run *"free | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $4/($3+$4)*100}'"* and retrieves a value. I save the value to an object model and in the controller I add it into modelandview to be displayed on the UI. When I refresh my page updated values will replace the old one(application gets restarted and starts up again; updating data)

**My question.**

How can I update the value on my web application without having to hit refresh to get the updated value from the server? I am looking for alternative ways to do this. I am Looking for ideas and tips to see what I am reaching for is possible, *not looking for code*.

**My Thoughts**

*Would AJAX help me on my objective?*
I think I need to have "free | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $4/($3+$4)100}'" to be continuously executed every minute or so. But it wouldn't work because I open connection to send script in. after that I close the connection because I don't want to leave connection open.

Comment: Yes, AJAX would serve the use case perfectly. What you need to do is choose a JavaScript API, such as JQuery, AngularJS, etc.. to serve you needs. Depending what your functional requirement is, you could use a timer to trigger same AJAX call over and over again.

Comment: AJAX is definitely going to help you out with this. You could look for sample widgets like news tickers which constantly refresh etc to get the idea. Also closing the connection for every request which is running so frequently is going to be taxing, so you should move the close part to a finally block rather than after every request.

Answer (score 0):

Think out of box. Please use socket programming for real time data demonstration.